# What is required to make a downloadable song?

Tags: download

I've just finished some courses on html and css, and am moving on to learning other languages.  But as of yet, I don't know any other languages at all.

I'm learning to code to build my music website.

The most important thing to me is for people to download the songs I put up on the site.

I'm not asking for the code to do this.  I want to know what is required so that I can learn how to do it.

I don't want people to download it simply by right clicking on the file and saving it.  I want them to click on the link and their browser starts downloading it.

I've tried to search on forums and youtube and on this site, but what I've found is either not what I wanted or is beyond my understanding.

So, I'd appreciate a simple guide in what to learn to be able to create a link where, when someone clicks on it, the browser is prompted to download the audio file.

Here's my HTML.  I've labeled where I plan to put my download link.

```
    <table>
                <tr><!--Off The Grid-->
<!--Song Title -->  <td>Off The Grid</td>
<!--Audio File -->  <td>
                        <object width="200px" height="15px">
                            <param name="src" value="../audio/off_the_grid_michael_pitluk.mp3">
                            <param name="autoplay" value="false">
                            <param name="controller" value="true">
                            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
                            <embed src="../audio/off_the_grid_michael_pitluk.mp3" autostart="false" loop="false" width="75px" height="40px" controller="true" bgcolor="#ffffff"></embed>
                        </object>
                    </td>
<!--Download Link--><td>Code for a button to download the song</td>
<!--Social Media --><td>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Fill in with Tweet button</li>
                            <li>Fill in with FB share button</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: simplest way I can think of , ZIP it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the server sends the file, and the way the browser is configured to use it depend on the action that the browser will take. The link itself has no input on this.

You need to look at [mime types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), and how they're used within HTTP Headers.

By way of example:

1. I click on a link to www.example.com/song.mp3, my browser sends a request to the server.
2. The server sends back the file with a [http header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) saying `content-type: audio/mp3`
3. My browser looks to see if it has anything that can deal with that file. If it does, it may play the file directly.  (This is what happens for html, and pictures)
4. If the browser is unable to find a handler then it may prompt you to save the file (or perhaps just start saving the file automatically).

To force the 'download' behavior, you can either configure the server to send a mimetype that the browser won't handle automatically. This approach can generally be done on a server configuration level. Note that you have no control over what the browser does, and some browsers may still try to handle the file anyway.

Alternatively, you can send the file as an attachment, if you set the content-disposition header, like `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="song.mp3"`. This approach generally requires some form of code (eg php, asp.net, ruby, etc) to do this behaviour.

Comment: Good explanation, Will.
@MichaelPitluck In either case (my answer or Will's), essentially all you're doing is confusing the browser so that the settings the person may have saved are no longer applicable (for example, what the browser should do when it encounters a `.mp3` file). See [this article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Changing_media_handling_behaviour#Unable_to_set_an_automatic_action) for more info.

Comment: @will Thanks Will. I read that article on mime types.  This seems to be the direction I want.  I want the file to work on most browsers -- simply, click the "download song" button and the song downloads.  What would be the safest, most reliable way to go be for this? Learning which language? Thanks.

Comment: @Michael All the popular server-side languages/frameworks should let you do this. I imagine to build your site you're going to need some other form of interactivity (eg log in, preferences, etc) - so this shouldn't need to be a factor in picking one.

Comment: If you rephrase your question to focus on a specific language, we can give you specific advice. Key words like 'attach file' with a language will probably find an answer to this already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your website should have a file called `.htaccess` in the site's "root directory" (the root directory is the folder that contains all the rest of your site's files). Assuming your site is running on an Apache server, if there is no such file then you should be able to add one. Just name the file `.htaccess` and place it inside the same folder where `index.php` or `index.html` lives (the root directory).

After that, inside your new `.htaccess` file, you can add something like this:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .mp3
```

... which will force all `.mp3` files to be downloaded rather than played in the browser.

There are other methods, but they depend on the language your site is written in. If it's strictly html though, this is the only option I can think of.

Hope that helps... Let me know if you need me to clarify anything. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Right now, I have an audio file on the page so people can stream it.  If I make it so that all .mp3's are to be downloaded, will this effect the .mp3 in the streamer? I have the code for this above in my original question.

Comment: I expected to learn new languages to pull this off effectively. I really want a method that will work in most browsers. So, I didn't mean to limit myself just to html. But, I'm going to try this out. I'm using hostgator for hosting, but I'm not sure what Apache is...